# visual basic 2008+ Erase all text prior to a line in a textbox

Tags: vb.net

This is my first post..
I have a textbox list like this:

```
apple
orange
banana
carrot
dog
cat
horse
cow
```

I need to search for "dog"
erase everything before "dog"
and keep everything after "dog"

```
For i = 0 To Val(TextBox3.Lines.Count)
        If TextBox3.Lines(i).ToString.StartsWith("dog") Then
            TextBox7.Text = TextBox3.Lines(i).ToString
Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
```

While the code above finds the line, I don't know how to erase everything above it and keep the rest. Any help would be appreciated and thank you.

Comment: the list is vertical not horizontal...not sure why it posted the way it did.

Comment: Why can't you use `.SubString()` a text box is just a long string that can have multiple lines in it. I would check to see if it has `"dog" and if it does then get the location of it by `dim dogIndex as int = TextBox3.Text.IndexOf("dog"). Then `TextBox7.Text = TextBox3.Text.SubString(dogIndex, TextBox3.Text.Length - dogIndex)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a loop to find the word dog, use the `.Contains()` function to see if the textbox contains the word dog.

```
If TextBox3.Text.Contains("dog") Then
 dim dogIndex as int = TextBox3.Text.IndexOf("dog")
TextBox7.Text = TextBox3.Text.SubString(dogIndex, TextBox3.Text.Length - dogIndex)
End If
```

This should get you only dog and everything after it.

Side note:
There is no need to cast `TextBox3.Lines.Count` with `Val()`. It is already a number.

Comment: This did it...I've been racking my brain all day. I'm comparing a web page with itself to see if it has changed. Unfortunately the site issues a unique value code embedded in it.